# Re-sizing the border in a Image View Blackberry10 cascades

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

i need to set a image-view it should have the square curve round at the edges ,How to do this can anyone send me some solution to do this

Answer (score 2):

Cascades qml does not support borders or rounded corners.  Unless someone has a better solution what I've done is to wrap the imageview in a container and use a 9-slice image for the container background.

A rough example:

```
Container {
    topPadding: 5
    leftPadding: 5
    rightPadding: 5
    bottomPadding: 5
    background: mybackground.imagePaint
    ImageView {
        imageSource: "asset:///images/image1.png"
    }
    attachedObjects: [
        ImagePaintDefinition {
            id: mybackground
            imageSource: "asset:///images/bgimage.amd"
        }
    ]
}
```

Adjust the padding as needed for thinner/thicker border.